# How do I change the footer in a Wordpress Customizr page?

Tags: themes, wordpress

The Customizr theme in Wordpress has lots of options that are fun to play with, but I'm stuck on one point. All my pages have a footer with a default copyright notice that I want to change, and nothing that I've found affects it. I'm probably overlooking the obvious, but I've spent quite a while trying to find it. Can someone tell me how I edit the footer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check here:
http://www.themesandco.com/snippet/altering-adding-footer-credits/
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/child-theme-footer
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/footer-copyright-text-change

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-change-copyright-and-powered-by-in-footer
http://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-to-edit-footer.html

**These all working if you have the possibility of editing the footer.php file.** (reading first and second link is enough but if you like you can read the rest).
But If you dont have access to that then you can hide it:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/removemodify-footer-copyright-text

```
.credit {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

The other solution would be Javascript solution. (Assuming the class is `credit`)
You should have a basic knowledge  of HTML

```
document.getElementsByClassName('credit')[0].innerHTML = "STH";
```

Copy that to console Ctrl+Shift+K (or I - Chrome) and increase 0 and click on what console gives you until you find the desired element. Then add `.innerHTML` to above and then you can use it to edit the footer on page startup. Like this:

[image: Example]

Comment: That worked. As a bonus, I learned how to create a child theme so that I was making the change cleanly. I added a child theme called "mycustomizr" and created a functions.php file there. Rather than figure out all the complexities of the PHP building the footer, I hard-coded the string to what I wanted it to be.